# How to let users drop pins in map view, that others can see?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, maps, mkmapview

How do i code a map view in which users can drop multiple pins, make annotations and add pictures?

my question has several parts to it really. i know how to code a map view in Xcode and how to put a pre-set pin however i want to be able to code something a bit more complex as it works in relation to an app i'm hoping to create!

1: how do i let a user of the app drop multiple pins to specify a certain location?

2: once the user has dropped a pin i want that he is able to add annotations and pictures?

3: finally i need that all the information of where the pins have been dropped, the annotations and the pictures can be seen by all other people using the app!

i have loked extensively into this and although i have found how to code basic maps into an app i have not been able to code the follow up parts!

thank you for reading my question and would really appreciate any suggestions that can be given. if you think there is a useful youtube video or a blog that you think could help me please put it at the bottom and i will look through it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant unless you store this data in some form of sever/cloud backend that you need to read independent of the user. Search for backend as a service, BAAS providers who provide APIs that you can use. I personally like www.parse.com

Comment: thanks, i have a server from a friend, but i'm not sure how i would link up the information created on the phone to be shared with all the other users?

Comment: Its a BIG hassel to connect to third party servers. Just look for BAAS for apps. Its a backend you can rent but is free during development.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Simple Example For how to Create Custom AnnotationView.**

Create custom `AnnotationView`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

// you can put here any controllers that you want. (such like UIImage, UIView,...etc)

@end
```

And in `.m file`

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

// Use Annotation Add `#import "AnnotationView.h"` in your relevant `.m file`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pCoordinate ;
pCoordinate.latitude = LatValue;
pCoordinate.longitude = LanValue;

// Create Obj Of  AnnotationView class  

AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:pCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;

    annotation.title = @"I m Here";
    annotation.subtitle = @"This is Sub Tiitle";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

**Above is simple Example of how to create `AnnotationView`.**

Comment: thank you, just wandering does this let the user of the app drop a pin or just the creator?